# Syncronus callback between content script and background.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I know there is no way to do it, but there is one way to do it specificly for my task. I want to execute window.stop() command in content script as soon as it's possible for the tabs which are inactive, to speedup google chrome startup, when I have over 30 tabs opened. Normally I would send a request from content script to background.html to find if current tab is inactive, wait for response and then execute window.stop(). But it's a bad idea because when 30 tabs are loading at the same time it takes too long for the response to respond. So I need a syncronus callback to stop page immidiatly after content script is activated. So I came up whith this solution. In background.html I do this

```
chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null,
function(tabs)
{ tabs.forEach(
  function(tab)
  { //check if tab is active
    //if it's not do chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "modified_url", selected: tab.selected})
  })
})
```

I tried 2 ways to modify url

1: google.com => google.com//

2: google.com => google.com???

When content script checks window.location.href and find there doubleslash or tripple question mark it does window.stop()

So chrome lives me no time to die while it's loading :)

But this way is not perfect though. A lot of pages automaticly correct such url's. And of course it's rude.

So maybe there is another way to to do something to the tabs using background.html so that content script knew about it to avoid Message Passing ?

Comment: I tried to use // and ??? at the same time and seems that none of those pages that do correction to it's url's still do it.

Comment: Oh no, youtube doesn't go with this url tease

Comment: Also tried this trick: change url to `"about:blank->http://google.com"` seems content_script doesn't work on such page and executeScript too.

Comment: Also tried this trick: change url to `file:///C:/tmp/1.htm?http://google.com` idea was to get favicon though content script via XMLHttpRequest, result: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101. This is normal, and only way to overcome start chrome whith special parameter(something like allow files read files...)

Comment: Found an issue right about my case, click a star to help me
`http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54257`
plee:)eease

Comment: I made it using "localStorage" and some asyncronus messaging, works perfectly, I called my extension "Stop all tabs". I'll put it on chrome webstore some time later...

Answer (score 0):

What about instead of:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "modified_url", selected: tab.selected});
```

doing:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "window.close()"});
```

Comment: You mean 
`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "window.stop()"});`
That's unfortunately doesn't work things would be easy if it did.
No other executeScript tricks work eather, even if you say
`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {code: "alert('!')"});`
it would be too late when message apear, whole page already would be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered one approach that allow to pass `boolean` values syncronously between content script and background html. It involves `webRequest` API.
What I do is sent `XMLHttpRequest` to `window.location.href` from content script.
Then I catch that request in background html and check it's url, if it's url match url of the tab that sent it, I either cancel the request, or let it run.
In that way content script can define whats happening in background because canceled request
returns `-1`.